# I am writing a SystemVerilog Testbench for a module that models a schematic, but don't know why transcript window saying no connection to port Y?

Tags: system-verilog, digital-logic, questasim, digital-design

The Following schematic is what I have modeled my module from. This is a SystemVerilog HW assignment in which we must use contiuous assignment(s). The signature model was given to us. Note there is no delays in the circuit. The problem I am having is that I don't really know what I am doing, for I am new to SystemVerilog and this is first time I have to write my own Testbench.
[schematic to model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxB7a.png)

Here is the module code:

```
module hw2_prob1 (
  input logic A, B, C, D,
  output logic Y
);  

  assign Y = (~(A|D)) & (B & C & ~D);


endmodule
```

This is what I have for my testbench code so far:

```
timeunit 1ns/1ns;

module tb_hw2_prob1();
 reg A, B, C, D;
 wire Y;



hw2_prob1 DUT(A, B, C, D, Y);

initial begin
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0000;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0001;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0010;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0011;

#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0100;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0101;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0110;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0111;

#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1000;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1001;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1010;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1011;

#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1100;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1101;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1110;
#5 {A,B,C,D} = 4'b1111;
end

initial begin #500 $finish; 
end

initial begin $monitor ($time,"%h %b", {A,B,C,D},Y);
end

endmodule
```

The assignment asks for 'The testbench for this circuit should set up a $monitor() statement in one initial block and generate all of the possible input combinations with a #5 ns delay between changing the inputs.'
We use QuestaSim or ModelSim for the simulations and here is the transcript and wave windows.
[Snip of tb project window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfVOQ.png)
[Snip of wave window tb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89cSd.png)

Do I have to add a clock? Why does it say missing connection for port Y? Does my wave window seem correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hw2_prob1 DUT(Y, A, B, D);` is missing `C` and has the wrong port order.

Pick one:

- `hw2_prob1 DUT(A, B, C, D, Y);` // connect by port order
- `hw2_prob1 DUT(.Y(Y), .A(A), .(B), .C(C), .D(D) );` // explicit connect by port name
- `hw2_prob1 DUT( .Y, .A, .B, .C, .D );` // implicit connect by port name
- `hw2_prob1 DUT( .* );` // auto connect by port name